# Keep previous data intact when changing "Column type" in Migration in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am using Ruby on rails  3.2.13 with ruby 1.9.3p374.
I have a table called "users" with column "last_sign_in_ip" having type:strings.

I want to convert this column into integer (for performance reasons).
I have written a migration to achieve this.

class ConvertStringIpsToIntegers < ActiveRecord::Migration

def up
    change_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip,    :integer
  end

def down
    change_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip,    :string
  end
end

But with this migration,I loose some of my previous data, which cannot be converted into perfect integer. (As they get converted to zero).
So, How can I alter this migration to ensure that, if the database was full of data before the migration, all data would still be intact afterwards.

Comment: How can you convert an IP to integer? It's a string.

Comment: I would like to convert string to integer for performance reasons.

Comment: But an IP cannot be expressed as an integer - "192.168.3.5" isn't an integer.